# Create 10000 text files with CMD with text

Tags: command-line, cmd

Create 10000 text file with DOS with text

so filename will be 1.txt and inside of it will be "numeric1.txt"

and the next text file will be 2.txt and inside of it will be "numeric2.txt"
...

and the next text file will be 10.txt and inside of it will be "numeric10.txt"

.
.
.
.
until the last text file will be 10000.txt and inside of it will be "numeric10000.txt"

Can you please help me with that ?

Regards

---

Update for this question

How I can make it write all this lines (with same number of files and file name like above)

```
@echo

cd..

cd..

cd /folder

text -u text -w numeric1.txt
```

Comment: which version of DOS? 6.22? Or the "cmd.exe" that comes inside win 7 ?

Comment: the "cmd.exe" that comes inside win 7 ; I need text files with text inside of it ; thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo OFF
FOR /L %%G IN (1,1,10000) DO echo numeric%%G.txt > %%G.txt
```

Comment: can you please read the Update for this question ;thanks

Answer (score 4):

```
FOR /L %A IN (1,1,10000) DO echo numeric%A.txt>%A.txt
```

Comment: can you please read the Update for this question ;thanks